# Iterator over a unique element without construction a container

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, std

I have a framework which has requires as input an iterator.
But sometime, I have a single element, so constructing a container seems like too much work.

```
T obj; // my unique object

std::vector<T> vec; // I want to avoid this
vec.push_back(T);

// Because the only use of the container is for this call
call(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));

// I want to do something like that
call(BeginFakeSingletonIt<T>(obj), EndFakeSingletonIt<T>());
```

I could create a special type of iterator, but doesn't something like that already exist in the standard library or boost?

Comment: Quick hack: `call(&obj, &obj + 1);`

Comment: @nwp: Not a hack, perfectly legit.

Comment: If you can rewrite your code to `T obj[1];`, then you can use `std::begin(obj), std::end(obj)`, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single element can be thought of as an array of size one.  So if we use that then a pointer to the object would be a pointer(iterator) to the start of the array and a pointer to one past then end of the array would just be that pointer incremented once.  So what you can do is use

```
call(&object, &object + 1)
```

And now you will only process the single object.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is a answer already, I'd suggest another approach: just add another overload to your call, which accepts an element itself, and make your iterator version calling the single element function in a loop.

This will make the code more straightforward, and have an added benefit of better optimized code in non-inlined cases.